Directus: Read Data flow node to ignore the current record
I have a flow in Directus , in this flow i need to read data from database but the current record that triggered the flow must be ignored.
The query in the flow ,according to the image just ignores the key 32 .
How do i use the IDs field to ignore the current record.
the 32 was just manually inserted to test.

